# How to write binary data to Cassandra blob - PHP

Tags: php, cassandra, blob

I'm tring to save any files in Cassandra ( CQL3), using YACassandraPDO

```
enter code here

        $tmpName = $_FILES['content']['tmp_name'];
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));

        $stmt = $cass_db->prepare ("INSERT INTO $table ( id, ctype, fname, content ) VALUES ( now(), :ctype, :fname, textAsBlob('$content')) ;");
        $stmt->bindValue (':ctype', $_FILES['content']['type']);
        $stmt->bindValue (':fname', $_FILES['content']['name']);
        $stmt->execute ();
```

if it's plain/text everything Ok
But i can't save any binary files,  I tried not to use  textAsBlob, - can't save any types of files
As a result
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'CQLSTATE[HY000] [2] Input length = 1'

Answer (score 1):

My decisions own:

**To Write**

```
    $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['content']['tmp_name']);
    $content = bin2hex($content);
    $stmt = $cass_db->prepare ("INSERT INTO $table ( id, ctype, fname, content ) VALUES ( now  (), :ctype, :fname, asciiAsBlob('$content') );");
    $stmt->bindValue (':ctype', $_FILES['content']['type']);
    $stmt->bindValue (':fname', $_FILES['content']['name']);
    $stmt->execute ();
```

**To Read**

```
    $stmt = $cass_db->prepare ("SELECT blobAsascii(content) as content, ctype, fname FROM $table WHERE id = $id;");
    $stmt->execute ();
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $fp = fopen('/tmp/'.$data[0]['fname'], 'w');
    $content = pack("H*",$data[0]['content']);
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge YACassandraPDO not stable. 
Please check this PHP library http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/

It is written by me, and how to work with it is similar to the PDO wrapper. Perhaps it will suit you.

Answer (score 0):

p.s. why you use: pack("H*",$data[0]['content']); 
instead more simple hex2bin($data[0]['content']) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write blob contents to cassandra using Blob class

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['content']['tmp_name']);
$blob = new \Cassandra\Blob($fileContent);
$content = $blob->bytes();
$stmt =  new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO $table ( id, ctype, fname, content ) VALUES ( ?,?,?,?");
    $result = $session->execute($statement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array(
        'arguments' => array($id, $ctype, $fname,$content)
    )));
```